# Making a copy of a vector from a method to another (java)

Tags: java, methods, vector, copy

So  i made this vector vcompras on a method and i was trying to do another vector that would be basically a complete copy of vcompras but with another name , velim , but i have no clue on how to do that . i have also previousely declared both vectors out side the methods.
im new to programing so please dont be harsh even if its not a smart question.

```
public class GO {

    Menu test2 = new Menu();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int dinheiro;
    int compra;
    double [] vcompras;
    double [] velim;
```

the vectors declared

```
double valorCompras( ){
        vcompras = new double[compra];
        double saldo = dinheiro;
        System.out.println("insira o valor de cada compra efetuada");
        if (compra > 0)
            for( int u = 0 ; u < vcompras.length ; u++ ){
                vcompras[u] = sc.nextDouble();
                saldo -= vcompras[u];

            }
        System.out.println("ficou com "+saldo+" de saldo na conta");
        return saldo;   

    }


    double [] elimCompras(){

        velim[] = vcompras[];

    }
```

and these are the methods.

Comment: `vcompras` is an `array`, not a Vector. What you are doing in your code is assigning the *same array* to two variables. Check `Arrays.copy` (warning! shallow copy! It will work as you expect for `double []`, but not for `Double []` -again, check the difference-)

Comment: how can it be an array , so far i have used vcompras has a vector on my main and it has worked perfectly , i have never needed to like adress specifically to collums or rows to remove the values it has in it.

Comment: In Java, `[]` is related to arrays (either creating one or accessing one). If you are confused by this, get back to reading the manual.

Comment: Oh, and the syntax error -> `velim = vcompras;`. That still does not create a copy, but at least copies the reference. And you need to `return` something.

Comment: shouldnt arrays be like [][] defining collums and rows respectivly and vectors be like [] defining?

Comment: i know i need to return something , in this case i would like to return the velim , but first i was trying to understand how to copy it.

Comment: *"shouldnt arrays be like [][] defining collums and rows respectivly"* No, that's a *matrix*. Please get a Java book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy it with a loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < vcompras.Length; i++)
{
     velim[i] = vercompras[i]; 
}
```

This copies the item at index i of vcompras to index i of velim and i is incremented after copying an item until there are no more items to copy. thus giving you an exact copy of vcompras.

And just so you know that is an array you are using not a vector 
You declare a vector like this  `Vector v = new Vector(size);` and add items by calling `v.addElement(item);`

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you it worked , i had allready tryed that but i must have made some  sort of bug in the code in which it didnt work.
also just searched for it and the java book i have its for its basics and its calls vector to things like double []..., so thank you for teaching me that.

Comment: youre Welcome if you want do learn more advaned things look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/